# gradient color is not applying on button in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am trying to set gradient color in Button (in android studio whose version is Arctic Fox).

**gradientbuttonmainactivity.xml**
I made this file in Drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#93501C"
        android:endColor="#A67E7E"
        android:type="linear"
        android:angle="360"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="25dp"/>

</shape>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnR"
        android:layout_width="275dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradientbuttonmainactivity"
        android:text="@string/register" />
```

but Button color is as it was, corners values applied but gradient values did'nt.

I searched it on google but didn't found any working solution.
In one stackoverflow answer, a writer said to change the colorPrimary (in theme.xml) with `@null`. I done this , and gradient color applied, but on Run, the app failed to open in the smartphone, however, it launched successfully.

So, the question is clear, How do I make the button with gradient color ? Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, try using

> androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton

instead of

> Button

it might be a recent change with Button and Android's material design, I've noticed on older projects what you have implemented works with Button but on a more recent project, that background is not working